# How to extract function prototype from an ELF file?

Tags: elf, extract, powerpc, function-prototypes

I have been searching quite a lot, but haven't found a way to extract function prototype, atleast the **argument types and return type** from an ELF executable file. Using GNU BinUtils or any other method.

I have tried using different options in readelf, nm and objdump, they list the symbols and function names, but how to know a function's argument types and return type?

I have a gut feeling that there should be a way to do it, can anyone throw some light on this?

Host: Windows 7

Target: elf for PowerPC architecture

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming your binary was built with debug info, you can get function type, argument types, etc. etc. by reading DWARF debug format, which `readelf -wi` will dump.

If your binary was produced by IBM's compiler, it may have (older) STABS debug info instead, which you can dump with `objdump -g`.

If your binary does *not* have the debug info, then you *can't* get the info you are looking for -- it's just not there.